# Java Jackson: parse three level JSON dynamic object structure

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I'm trying to use the Java Jackson ObjectMapper to parse a three level JSON object stucture with dynamic keys. I tried the following:

```
public class AssetsPushManifest {
    private Map<String, List<Asset>> manifest = new HashMap<>();

    public void addPushManifest(Resource manifestResource) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Map<String, Asset>> manifestData = mapper.readValue(manifestResource.getInputStream(), new TypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, Asset>>>() {});
        for (String requestedPathName : manifestData.keySet()) {
            if (!this.manifest.containsKey(requestedPathName)) {
                this.manifest.put(requestedPathName, new LinkedList());
            }
            List<Asset> requestedPath = this.manifest.get(requestedPathName);

            for (String servePath : manifestData.get(requestedPathName).keySet()) {
                Asset asset = manifestData.get(requestedPathName).get(servePath);
                asset.path = servePath;
                requestedPath.add(asset);
            }
        }

        ...
    }

    public class Asset {
        public String path;
        public String type;
        public Integer weight;
    }
}
```

To parse this:

```
{
  "theme/test-theme/index.html": {
    "theme/test-theme/somestyling.css": {
      "type": "document",
      "weight": 1
    }
  }
}
```

But it won't work, why oh why? Is it too many levels? (still Java beginner here)

The end goal is to parse the several JSON structures like above into a structure like Map> so any other ways of doing this would also be fine.

Comment: What is the output?

Comment: The Asset object doesn't represent correctly the JSON file

Comment: Yeah it has one extra property, path, is that the reason maybe? I thought I could just use that class even if it had one extra property and then set that property from the "parent" key afterwards.

Comment: @Guts the goal is just to read x amount of manifest JSONs like the example and create an object structure like Map<String, List<Asset>> that will later be used for HTTP2 Server Push responses. When a single HTML page is requested it should also push all the related resources in the same connection. But first I need to read the manifests from the format that the Polymer framework generates (as in the example JSON)

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this in a different way: parse the json into a map: if you give Jackson a map as type reference, it will deserialize the JSON into multi-level map:

```
`Map<String, Object> manifestData = mapper.readValue(manifestResource.getInputStream(), Map.class);`
```

Now that the json parsing hurdle is behind us, it is easier to construct an instance of an `Asset` by querying the map. I would do it by adding a constructor to the `Asset` class:

```
public Asset(Map<String, Object> manifestData) { 
    Map<String, Object> assetData = (Map<String, Object>)manifestData.values().iterator().next();  // get the single value of the map
    this.path = assetData.keySet().iterator().next();
    this.type = assetData.get("type"); 
    this.weight = assetData.get("weight");
}
```